# What would be a basis of function vector space U = {f ∈ F(X) ∶ f(−x)−f(x) = 0 for every x ∈ X}, knowing X = {−2,−1,0,1,2}.

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

**Note : This question is from a school assignment.**

> Let $X = {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2}$, and set U = {$f \in F(X) \mid f(-x) -
> > f(x) = 0$  for every  $x \in X$}. Consider the following functions
> defined on $X$:
>
> $g_1(x) = 1$
>
> $g_2(x) = \frac{1}{4}x^2(1-x^2)$
>
> $g_3(x) = \frac{1}{3}x^2(4-x^2)$
>
> for every $x \in X$.
>
> Question: Prove that $S = {g_1, g_2, g_3}$ is a basis of $U$.

My thoughts:
I know that to prove that a set is a basis of U, I have to prove that it spans U and that it is linearly independent.

I can prove its linear independency, but when it comes to proving it spans U, I cannot think of a way to do so.

The basis has 3 elements, but in my understanding U should have an infinite dimension. For example, $x^6 \in U$ and $cos(x) \in U$, too, as $x^6 = (-x)^6$, and $cos(x)=cos(-x)$. But clearly, both functions are not a linear combination of $g_1, g_2$, or $g_3$.

I went to my teacher's office hour and he explained to me that a function is essentially just a relation between its domain and its image. So if two functions produces the same coordinate in its image for all their domains, then they are same. This makes sense to me, but then it makes me wonder why the $dim(U)=3$, since $1$ and $x^2$ would technically span all polynomial of even degree, which p(x)=p(-x).

Thank you, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the domain and range of $F$? Over what field is this vector space defined?

Comment: If you are talking about something like the space of real valued functions on $X$ then this is clearly three dimensional, as any such function is determined by its values on $\{0,1,2\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the domain of the considered functions is $X=\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$ and not the whole real line. Moreover, $g_1(0)=1,g_{2,3}(0)=0$, so you easily get the needed coefficient for $g_1$. Afterwards, $g_2(\pm 1)=0$ and since your coefficient for $g_1$ is already determined, the value $f(\pm 1)$ uniquely determines the coefficient of $g_3$. Finally, $g_3(\pm 2)=0$, so the value $f(\pm 2)$ uniquely determines the coefficient of $g_2$.